# Files in NTFS partition marked as green

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows, disk, partitioning

I created a NTFS partition for all my files to use in Ubuntu and Windows, and every directory and file is marked as green, even if I create new directory.

I tried with chmod and chown, adding uid=1000,gid=1000,group=1000 in Edit Mount Options but nothing from these solved the problem.

How can I fix this ? Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem of having them green?

Comment: They are executable I think ...and i want to change this

Comment: NTFS doesn't support Linux permissions anyway.

Comment: @Pilot6 [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/74851/931617) says otherwise..

Comment: But they are still marked as green, that means they are still executable.. Nothing changed

Comment: Attempting to create the mapping for permissions is a nightmare. Best not to attempt it. Just set correct ownership & permissions with fstab when mounted. What is your current fstab entry. Post above in question. If you used a umask of 002 on NTFS then 777 - 002 makes every file excuteable which you do not want.